# Scraping h5 header text in between div tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to attempt webscraping product prices from [this website](https://gs25.mn/product-catalogue?page=1). How would I go around getting a text value inside a h4 heading in between div classes?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="product-item">
<a href="/product-catalogue?pid=6963">
<div class="list-item-image">
<img src="https://app.digitalconcept.mn/upload/media/product/0001/05/thumb_4760_product_thumb.png" alt="Кофе Bestcup rich creamy 3NI1 1ш">
</div>
<h5>Кофе Bestcup rich creamy 3NI1 1ш</h5>
<div class="price">500₮</div>
</a>
</div>
```

**My currently used code:**

```
# function to parse
def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    data = response.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'product-item')]")
    for item in data:
        yield {
            "name": data.xpath(".//*[@class='h5']/text()").get(),
            "price": data.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'price')]/text()").get()
        }
```

**My current output:**
{'name': None, 'price': '3,700₮'}

**My expected output:**
{'name': 'Үхрийн махтай кимбаб', 'price': '3,700₮'}

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having difficulty finding the element as it's not in English. Also, your expected output and the provided `HTML` are also different. So I am adding the answer according to the provided `HTML`

You should change your code ***from***

```
def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    data = response.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'product-item')]")
    for item in data:
        yield {
            "name": data.xpath(".//*[@class='h5']/text()").get(),
            "price": data.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'price')]/text()").get()
        }
```

***To***

```
def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    data = response.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'product-item')]")
    for item in data:
        yield {
            "name": item.xpath(".//h5/text()").get(),
            "price": item.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'price')]/text()").get()
        }
```